Slice append data is incomplete
I have updated my code. Is there anything that can be adjusted or optimized? append(pcapData, append([]byte(nil), buff.Bytes()...)) Will frequent append affect efficiency?
type frame struct {
    Length int
    Data   []byte
}
    
var pcapInfos map[string][]frame

var pcapBytes map[string][][]byte
    
func cache() {
    pcapBytes = make(map[string][][]byte)

    for name, frames := range pcapInfos {
        var pcapData [][]byte
        var buff bytes.Buffer

        for _, frame := range frames {
            if buff.Len()+frame.Length > 4096 {
                // Append a copy of the buffered data
                pcapData = append(pcapData, append([]byte(nil), buff.Bytes()...))
                buff.Reset()
            }
            buff.Write(frame.Data)
        }

        // Append remaining data if any
        if buff.Len() > 0 {
            pcapData = append(pcapData, append([]byte(nil), buff.Bytes()...))
        }

        pcapBytes[name] = pcapData
    }
}


bytes.Buffer will reuse the underlying slice (the docs state that "[it] retains the underlying storage for use by future writes"), so this code can append the same []byte slice multiple times.

From bytes.Buffer.Bytes(): "The slice is valid for use only until the next buffer modification (that is, only until the next call to a method like Buffer.Read, Buffer.Write, Buffer.Reset, or Buffer.Truncate)"

Seems like you don't need a bytes.Buffer at all -- bytes.Buffer is for when you want an io.Writer that constructs a slice of bytes, but here you're just using it as a complicated way of joining multiple []byte slices into one. var buff []byte works more simply, and you can use append where you're currently using buff.Write.

You didn't write a valid Go program:
    pcapBytes ：= make(map[string][][]byte)

The ： (Fullwidth Colon , Unicode U+FF1A) character is no valid operator in Go. If you meant := you'll declare a local variable which will shadow the global declaration.
    for name,frames in range pcapInfos{

There is no in operator in go, it should be :=
                pcapData = append(pcapData, buff.Bytes())
                buff.Reset()

The documentation of Buffer.Bytes says: “The slice is valid for use only until the next buffer modification (that is, only until the next call to a method like Buffer.Read, Buffer.Write, Buffer.Reset, or Buffer.Truncate).”
So the slice appended to pcapData becomes invalid in the next line.
            _, err := buff.Write(frame.Data)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

Buffer.Write: “The return value n is the length of p; err is always nil.”
